# R low quality graph in graphic device

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to figure out what is going on with my plot render. 
Yesterday I produced a `geom_smooth` with `ggplot2` but the output was very low.
for the example when I render this code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

I got this graph, and the line is not "sharp" at what it always does:

**Crude render**

[image]

Moreover, when I use the command `ggsave ()` to produce the plot, the line renders look great as ever.

- the render is the same if I use R GUI or Rstudio
- I try to reinstall R and Rstudio, nothing do
- I could not reproduce this "bug" on another computer and my Linux server

Did someone have any clue?

Comment: The R-Tcl/Tk interface has different graphical settings, to save on memory. Just save the plot as pdf or svg...

Comment: yes, i could do that.

However, the render in shiny seem to be link with the device render, therfore the shiny application does not look good.   

Plus i really would like to know why.

Comment: What OS are you working on and what is returned when you evaluate `capabilities()` in R?

Comment: my OS i a windows 7 pro  

and  

`capabilities()   
       jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua    http/ftp 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE 
    sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv         NLS     profmem 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
      cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE `